# C# custom linked list node deletion - Garbage collection

Tags: c#, linked-list, garbage-collection

Following is code to create a custom C# list and delete a node in the list:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ListNode rootNode = CreateList();
    DeleteNode(rootNode.ChildNode);
    ....
}

private static ListNode CreateList()
{
    ListNode node1 = new ListNode()
    {
        Value = 1,
        ParentNode = null;
    }

    ListNode node2 = new ListNode()
    {
        Value = 2,
        ParentNode = node1
    }

    node1.ChildNode = node2;

    return node1;
}

private static void DeleteNode(ListNode node2)
{
    node2.ParentNode.ChildNode = null;
    node2 = null;
}
```

Can I assume that after the call to DeleteNode(rootNode.ChildNode), the child node(or node2) will be garbage collected?

Comment: No you cannot assume it will be garbage collected but you can assume if GC happens, it will be collected because it is no longer rooted.

Comment: If you want to explicitly free resources, you can use the `IDisposable` interface https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.idisposable?view=netframework-4.7.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not necessarily (it may or may not kick in at this point), the GC process  usually results in a performance hit and the algorithm is optimized to reduce it, thus it wont kick in for each opportunity to clean the unreferenced objects. You can force the GC by calling `GC.Collect();` explicitly but it is discouraged/not recommended as you probably not taking into account all of the consideration taken by the algorithm - so don't do it.
You can read [this](https://www.telerik.com/blogs/understanding-net-garbage-collection) *short* article to understand how the algorithm woks.